# How can i show the layer like polygon cover all marker in mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, polygon

error in my code, i can't create a hull by turf because it isn't format input
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eAWN.png)

```
var pointData = [
    [-74.5, 40],
    [-74.6, 40.1],
    [-74.4, 39.9],
    [-74.55, 39.95],
    [-74.65, 40.05],
    [-74.35, 40.15]
];

var pointGeoJSON = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: pointData.map(function(coord) {
        return {
            type: 'Feature',
            geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: coord
            }
        };
    })
};

var hull = turf.convex(pointGeoJSON);
```

Comment: i can't create a hull because the format input is wrong

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? I believe your coordinates, laid out like you have them in your `pointData` array, do not make a convex area. Will explain in greater detail, once you provide the error.